# Mount volume group(OnApp)

Tags: linux, lvm, xen

I am attempting to get OnApp setup in a lab using the following documents: [OnApp Installation Guide](https://docs.onapp.com/display/3116core/OnApp+Cloud+v3.1.x+Free+Version+Installation+Guide)

I am one step away from success and to my knowledge based on the information given and my(limited) understanding of LVM what is being asked is not possible.  [Data Store Instructions](https://docs.onapp.com/display/3116core/Install+Data+Store) says to create a PV and then create a VG, I have done both of these steps and can see that it was successful, however the 'datastore' must be mounted on the hypervisor.

This is a Xen hypervisor which to my understanding will create a logical volume for each VM so I shouldn't create an LV myself.

The output from lvs, pvs and vgs seems to be correct however I have hit a wall here.  Any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Command Output:

```
[root@hv1 ~]# lvs
LV       VG         Attr   LSize   Origin Snap%  Move Log Copy%  Convert
LogVol00 VolGroup00 -wi-ao 858.72G
LogVol01 VolGroup00 -wi-ao  72.69G
[root@hv1 ~]# pvs
PV         VG                   Fmt  Attr PSize   PFree
/dev/sda2  VolGroup00           lvm2 a--  931.41G      0
/dev/sdd1  onapp-p3n9zel3zirdlf lvm2 a--  499.94G 499.94G
[root@hv1 ~]# vgs
VG                   #PV #LV #SN Attr   VSize   VFree
VolGroup00             1   2   0 wz--n- 931.41G      0
onapp-p3n9zel3zirdlf   1   0   0 wz--n- 499.94G 499.94G
[root@hv1 ~]# fdisk -l

Disk /dev/sda: 1000.2 GB, 1000204886016 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 121601 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sda1   *           1          13      104391   83  Linux
/dev/sda2              14      121601   976655610   8e  Linux LVM

Disk /dev/sdd: 536.8 GB, 536870912000 bytes
255 heads, 63 sectors/track, 65270 cylinders
Units = cylinders of 16065 * 512 = 8225280 bytes

Device Boot      Start         End      Blocks   Id  System
/dev/sdd1               1       65270   524281243+  8e  Linux LVM


[root@hv1 ~]# ls /dev/ | grep  onapp-p3n9zel3zirdlf
[root@hv1 ~]# ls /dev/mapper/
control  VolGroup00-LogVol00  VolGroup00-LogVol01
```

**EDIT:**I attempted to create an LV, formatted and mounted it to a folder and still had no luck.
Edit: The issue was not in LVM at all it was an RTFM issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you cannot mount a volume group,  but you can work with a volume, the volume is the final part of rule

```
[pv]->[vg]->[lv]->{fs on the volume}
```